Kubuntu not available in GRUB
I have a Kubuntu and Windows Dual Boot set up. Everything was working fine. However, when I turned on my computer this morning, my Kubuntu install was just missing from GRUB.
I tried using Ubuntu's Boot Repair Utility to reinstall GRUB and fix it, but the Kubuntu installation is still missing. I'm able to access all the files using all the files using the Ubuntu Boot Repair live usb.
I'd really appreciate any help urgently. I'm very much a beginner in Linux, so I'd appreciate any help/explanation.
Details:
My EFI System is on /dev/nvme0n1p1
My Linux filesystem is /dev/nvme0n1p7
My Windows OS is on /dev/nvme0n1p3
I'm using an Asus ROG Zephyrus
Here is a pastebin of the GRUB information of my system from boot repair:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/yDTX2q8dmB/

I might try Boot-Repair's advanced mode and totally reinstall grub & latest kernel. https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ How did you install nVidia driver? From Ubuntu repository?

@oldfred I tried using the Boot-Repair's advanced mode to purge and reinstall grub and the kernel but that only removed the memory test options in Grub and didn't bring back Kubuntu. For the nvidia drivers I used nvidia-detect to automatically detect and install the appropriate drivers for my system. I also followed nvidia's official guide to install cuda drivers.

You say Kubuntu, but it looks like you are using Mint as repair flash drive. "Live-session OS is Linuxmint" Use your Kubuntu live installer to make repairs. You may be getting different versions of grub & kernel from Mint repositories.
